# Dell Precision T3600 no post display, monitor do not receive power

Tags: desktop

when I turn on the computer, it turns on fine, power is ok, CD-ROM works, but no light on keyboard and mouse. HDD works and fans. I have searched the dell community website and support, best [solution](https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Fixed-Workstations/Dell-T3600-doesn-t-POST-no-codes-no-lights-no-beeps-full/td-p/7441658) is this that kind a similar to the problem. I also have tried other solutions suggested by the dell support but still no luck. Any idea?

Comment: Start by removing all add in cards and only 1 memory module to attempt a post, then try a different memory module. It is a hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Moab, I removed RAM and tested then 1 by 1 by turn of the computer, unplug between each testing of each RAM still no post. I am hoping not that all 4 is failed by I tried a different RAM stick from another DELL computer still the same.